# Jquery #id ul li a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="Day-events-content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <time date="12-12-2013">
            <em>12-12-2013</em>
            <small>18:00</small>
            </time>
            <a href="#">EU driving</a>
            <p class="hidden">Lorem</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

$("#Day-events-content ul li a").click(function (event){
   alert('o');
});
```

I want to do simple toggle() but code above it doesn't work.If I change #Day-events-content
it works if click on elements in id area.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qkmRV/ What were you using to toggle the p element?

Comment: `<time>` is closed  after `<small>` but what is the `</div>` at the end? also use '.toggle()' instead of `.click()`

Comment: @jplara why would he use .toggle instead of click?

Comment: @kevin B that's what he said. he wanted to do a simple toggle

Comment: Yes I would like to toggle the p element.

Comment: instead of the alert from kevin's fiddle add `$('p.hidden').toggle();`

Comment: It works on fiddle but on my localhost it doesn't.How it's possible?

Comment: you don't have jquery? the id is misspellleeedd? incorrect markup? check firebug or dev tools

Comment: `.toggle()` event handler is removed in jQuery 1.9 and up: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#Day-events-content ul li a").click(function (event){
    $('p.hidden').toggle();
});
```

Comment: $("#Day-events-content") works on my localhost.When I want $("#Day-events-content ul li a") it doesn't. no idea

Comment: It works on my localhost when it's hardcoded - but when JS creates Day-events-content list it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can start your ID with a capital letter.  Necro comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$("#Day-events-content ul li a").click(function (event){
   $('.hidden').toggle();
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAZkH/)

Comment: Double checked - still doesn't work.in Console I get - event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. // All html is generated by js.

Comment: OK it works. instead .click() -> .on()